# Functions are not valid as a react child.This may happen if you return a component instead of <Component/> from render

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am getting this error and its referring me to this  Functions Are Not Valid As A React Child.This May Happen If You Return A Component Instead Of  From Render.
How can I solve this issue? Or go about solving this problem, please help!!!

```
    const App: () => React$Node = () => {
      return (

      <View >
          <Main {...this.props}/>
      </View>



And this is my Main component

    import React,{Component} from 'react';
    import {View,Text} from 'react-native';
    import createStore from './store/createStore';
    import AppContainer from './AppContainer';

    export default class Main extends Component{
        renderApp(){
           const initalState=window.__INITIAL_STATE__;
            const store=createStore(initalState);

        return(
            <AppContainer store={store}/>
        );

    }
    render(){
        return this.renderApp;
    }
}

  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `return this.renderApp()` so you're actually executing the function

Answer (score 0):

Change your main component to this

```
export default class Main extends Component{
        renderApp = () =>{
           const initalState=window.__INITIAL_STATE__;
            const store=createStore(initalState);

        return(
            <AppContainer store={store}/>
        );

    }
    render(){
        return this.renderApp();
    }
}
```

hope it helps